# Is it possible to short-hand hyphenated styles in LESS, similar to how it is done in SASS

Tags: less

In SASS, I like to use the short-hand feature that allows me to DRY-ly write the following code for hyphenated styles in this syntax:

```sass
.a {
  background: {
    color: orange;
    image: url(bg.jpg);
    repeat: no-repeat;
    position: center;
  }
}
```

Is the same kind of syntax feature in LESS?

Comment: Did that post answer your question mate? If yes, please consider marking it as accepted. If not, please clarify further.

Answer (score 2):

No, Less currently does not have such a feature available (but it could be a good feature request). The below is the closest that I can suggest in Less but it is not really much of an improvement.

```css
.demo{
    @bg: background;
    @{bg}-color: #aaa;
    @{bg}-image: url(img.jpg);
    @{bg}-repeat: no-repeat;
    @{bg}-position: center;
}
```

Or you can probably write a mixin for all the `background-*` properties and keep the code DRY. The below is a basic sample (not to be used as-is because the guards are very basic). Other than that there is not much else you could do.

```css
/* mixin */
.background(@color; @image: none; @repeat; @position) {
    & when (iscolor(@color)){
        background-color: @color;
    }
    & when (isurl(@image)){
        background-image: @image;
    }
    & when (iskeyword(@repeat)){
        background-repeat: @repeat;
    }    
    & when (iskeyword(@position)){
        background-position: @position;
    }
}

/* mixin usage */
.demo{
    .background(black; url(a.jpg); no-repeat; center);
}
#demo1{
    .background(blue; url(demo.jpg); repeat; left);
}
```